# monero-wallet-qui removing from PC

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

My Monero GUI wallet cannot connect to `monerod`. I get this:

```
Status connection error
```

This is what I had tried:

- I did a completely new installation.
- I have deleted `C:/ProgramData/bitmonero` folder.
- I deleted the unzipped folder containing Monero GUI wallet.
- I downloaded the wallet again.
- I ran Monero GUI wallet but the old wallet is still open and asked me for a password.
- After I set a password the wallet will open with 0 balance and status disconnected.

Any idea to solve that? `monerod` seems open and work correctly.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

To completely remove Monero GUI Wallet from Windows 10 you need to:

- Delete folder `bitmonero` in: `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\`
- Delete folder `Monero` in: `%userprofile%\Documents\Monero`
- Delete registry entries `The Monero Project`:

  ```
  regedit > Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\The Monero Project\
  ```